# Huge citadel log files

Tags: ubuntu, logging, log-files, disk-space-utilization, citadel

I noticed today that my mysql server was not starting up anymore. Checking the error logs, it showed that it didn't have enough disk space. I thought that's really weird since there's nothing on my server that could possibly take up 30GB. After digging around I observed my citadel logs are taking up a massive 22GB of space in the `/var/lib/citadel/data/` directory:

[image]

This is split in lots of smaller (still big) log files:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it in the future?

**EDIT**: Here's a sanitized sample of one of the log files:

[image]

Comment: Are they text logs or database logs?

Comment: Not sure. They contain some human-readable text (looks like config changes, some emails, etc) but also contain some non-human-readable stuff.

Comment: Can you post a sanitized snipped of one of the logs?

Comment: I have now posted a sample above.

Answer (score 2):

They're database logs.  Citadel has functionality to delete them.  Just turn on automatic log pruning and the logs that are committed to the database will go away.