# Citadel not working after deleting log files

Tags: ubuntu, log-files, citadel

I am running a citadel mail server with webcit on an Ubuntu server. I've been having the problem described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/751688/huge-citadel-log-files) and made the rushed decision of removing all of the log files. This created an unexpected issue; when trying to access the mail server through webcit, the following message pops up and nothing else happens:

> This program was unable to connect or stay connected to the Citadel
>   server. Please report this problem to your system administrator. Read
>   More...

Nothing I found online helped. The `cdb.<xx>` files are still there and intact, but all the log files are gone.

**How can I get citadel to work again, without the log files?**

Note: I need to keep ALL the settings and accounts I currently have, but the messages themselves are expendable.

Answer (score 0):

An Idea.
Recreate blank log files in the same name as they were before.

You may have to setup a dummy server in the cloud if you have no idea of the file names.

Comment: Sadly there was thousands of log files and I don't have the number so that won't work. I already tried copying a few from another server of mine but that didn't work :(